# How to get param value in as3 from Html?

Tags: html, actionscript-3

I Want get Param values(src) from Html to AS3 that allows us to maintain in communication our Flash applications with the server.
We often need to assign to a SWF a value in entry using the HTML of the page in which the SWF itself is inserted.
My Problem is While getting values(src) From html to As3 ,The Html page is working in Intenet Explorer only.I Cannot get in From Mozila and Google Chrome.
here my As3 Coding

```
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
var sourceId:String = loaderInfo.parameters.src;
trace(sourceId);
```

Here I cannot Get the Value of sourceId

my Html Coding

```
param name="flashvars" value="src=f785"
```

While running my Swf in Html, I take this src Value.Its Working in
Internet Explorer Only, It's not Working in Mozila and Google Chrome.

Comment: please post your complete embed code

Comment: finally I got Answer Sir,Thank you

Comment: <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="textchat" >        
    <param name="movie"  />
    <param name="quality" value="high"  />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
 <param name="movie" flashvars="src=f785"  />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  >
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
     </object> My Coding

Comment: It Support firefox ,Google Chrome As well As Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you need to put everything twice in your html, once for IE once for everything else:

```
  <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="780" height="420">
    <param name="movie" value="myContent.swf" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="myContent.swf" width="780" height="420">
    <!--<![endif]-->
      <p>Alternative content</p>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
  </object>
```

In your case you have likely missed adding the params to the `<object>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this param-value pair to your swf path: `<param value="...swf?src=f785" name="movie">`
**upd**
this is the code i use for static embedding:

```
<object height="500" width="500" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" id="lol" name="lolo"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="movie" value="....swf?src=f785"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><embed height="500" width="500" src="....swf?src=f785" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="lol" name="lolo"></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) - crossbrowser solution for inserting swf to html.
2. Try [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#includeExamplesSummary) to be able to pass values from html/javascript to swf at runtime
3. Your code for reading FlashVars looks correct.

Comment: It doesn't support Firefox. And I'm not sure why reading "src" doesn't work. Try to use another example.